# Travis CI works correctly, but Coveralls doesn't see the builds

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, travis-ci, coveralls

I have a repository on Github, a PHP Symfony app with a PHPunit test suite (https://github.com/antodippo/ccmusicsearch), and Travis CI is correctly checking the build every time I push (https://travis-ci.org/antodippo/ccmusicsearch/builds).

I linked to a Coveralls account to my Travis and Github account, and I configured my .travis.yml file this way:

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.5
  - 5.6

before_script:
  - composer self-update
  - composer install

script:
  - mkdir -p build/logs
  - phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml.dist

after_success:
  - bin/coveralls -v
```

and I put this lines in my [phpunit.xml.dist](https://github.com/antodippo/ccmusicsearch/blob/master/app/phpunit.xml.dist):

```
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
</logging>
```

but Coveralls stills says that there have been no build (https://coveralls.io/github/antodippo).

What am I forgetting?

Comment: check better on your travis build: here the error: https://travis-ci.org/antodippo/ccmusicsearch/jobs/101809466#L473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that with that phpunit.xml.dist configuration the clover.xml file was created in /app/builds/logs/clover.xml. So I changed phpunit script in .travis.yml this way:

```
phpunit --coverage-clover build/logs/clover.xml -c app
```

so the file is generated correctly in /app/builds/logs/clover.xml, and Coveralls now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

sorry not enough reputation to comment.
I have the same issue. On travis ci i get the coverage percent of my files, but nothing on coveralls.io 
I noticed that coveralls is saying

> We detected this repo isn’t badged! Grab the embed code to the right, add it to your repo to show off your code coverage, and when the badge is live hit the refresh button to remove this message.

i have the same message and i added the badge. Looks like it won't sync

### Edit :

here what i did to fix my

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException] coverage_clover XML file is not readable

and made the coveralls work

-`.travis yml` script :

```
script:
- phpunit -c app/ src/ --coverage-clover build/logs/clover.xml

after_success:
- bin/coveralls -v
```

-`phpunit.xml.dist`:

```
....
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage" title="coverage" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true"
   lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
    <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
    <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
</logging>
...
```

-created a `.coveralls.yml` file at the root of my SF project :

```
coverage_clover: build/logs/clover.xml
json_path: build/logs/coveralls-upload.json
exclude_no_stmt: true
```

make sure you have your `bin/coveralls` folder at the root of your SF project